# Provide option to filter jobs by natural languages

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs, languages

I got an email notification about [this job](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/110051/senior-frontend-developer-w-m-check24), opened it and I was like *what*?

I don't know German (*location and Google says so*). While I'm open to jobs  in foreign countries matching my skills, I not the man for the job if it requires speaking the local language out of the box.

So can we introduce an option for the employers to specify mandatory languages that the candidate should speak and an option for the candidates to filter only the jobs that requires the languages he knows (*something similar to filtering tags in existing search*)?

Well I know it adds a little bit of extra work from the employers part, but we can make it more friendly by:

- Making English as default (they won't have to put extra effort if
  it's the only requirement)
- There can be a checkbox for including their local language, just like the one that says "always include my location" in the current system

(Those are just my ideas maybe someone can come up with better ones)

---

Either this, or don't let the employers post jobs in languages other than English in Stackoverflow main site, Let them post it in the corresponding stackoverflow versions like [es.stackoverflow.com](https://es.stackoverflow.com/), if there is one.

Comment: for a star tag the jobs with [german] so I can filter using negative filter [english][french]-[german]

Comment: There's a [moderator answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344686/5211833) on why job ads in a foreign language are allowed. Gist is: companies can decide A) which language to use in their ad and B) whom to target. SO isn't going to implement a language checkbox on either side, as they'd lose revenue.