# Are job listings in another language allowed?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

I found [this job listing](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/119552/d%C3%A9veloppeur-fullstack-ruby-on-rails-exp%C3%A9riment%C3%A9-jobteasercom?searchTerm=ruby-on-rails&offset=23&sort=i) while going through Jobs today. If you read French, go ahead and take a look - it's entirely in French.

Are non-English listings allowed on Jobs? I don't think I've seen any before today.

Comment: related: [Provide option to filter jobs by natural languages](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/321006/2279200)

Comment: That is one real fine job offer, also.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Are non-English listings allowed on Jobs?

Yes, they are. We have listings in German, Arabic, Hebrew and other languages.

When a company needs local people who do not need to be proficient in English, there is really no reason to not let them advertise on the platform in the native language.

Comment: That doesn't seem "Okay", since SO is English-only. We ask users to do everything in English. I'm surprised there's no such language restriction on jobs, especially since it's on http://stackoverflow.com/ If it were on a different domain, like http://jobs.stackexchange.com, it'd make more sense, imo.

Comment: Seems odd to me. SO is english only, the CV (I presume) is supposed to be english only. And most developers absolutely need to speak fluent english. Where is that market for developers that can't speak english? That'd make you unemployable

Comment: I don't see the problem, Cerbrus and Magisch. If the job listing is not in a language you understand, then it is simply not targetted at you and it would be pointless to translate it.

Comment: @Stijn seems then that at least they should be hidden by default unless you select "also show listings in $language"

Comment: Now that I take a closer look at [the page](http://stackoverflow.com/jobs), I'm seeing a bunch of German listings. Why are they shown to me? Also, why doesn't that page make use of the geolocation API?

Comment: @Magisch - how would one select that? That would make such listings completely useless to employers, while ensuring developers who are qualified to such jobs never see them.

Comment: @Cerbrus - "that page"?

Comment: @Oded Setting in the preferences, maybe. Maybe even make it prominent or make people fill it out when they first fill out their CV. There is no use (for employers and employee alike) to show non-english job listings to anyone but the people speaking that language.

Comment: It's not uncommon to select a list of languages you speak, on profiles like that. @Oded: The job listing page.

Comment: @Oded In fact, if anything, being shown job listings that you obviously and knowingly would never apply to at all is a failure of the filter system, and I'd think that would merit correction. Especially since its so easy to ask "List the (real world) languages you speak here:" when you're already asking applicants to fill out a CV

Comment: I would hope most developers are interested in including spoken languages in their CV anyways, since speaking more then one is an important asset to employers.

Comment: And the complaints about non-English posts being closed (but my CV is in French!) coming in 3...2...