# Why am I seeing a German job advert?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs, advertising

Today I saw a German job advertisement on the Stack Overflow home page. I happen to speak German and live reasonably close to Germany (only 200km or so), but have no indications on my computer that I would like to work there or do many things in German. So why am I seeing a German job ad?

[image]

---

You asked us to keep you posted if the problem persisted, so hereby: it does to this day:

[image]

I'll just block the "feature" from now on.

Comment: I would assume it's German because they entered the benefits only in German. Not sure why the system thinks it's ok to show it to you though

Comment: If you're living close to germany, then you may have got an IP from your provider which is registered to be located in Germany? Or you're using a VPN with a german address.

Comment: @Tom No, since I am in the Netherlands, I'm registered there (Amsterdam, or Delft afaik). And as I said: there's nothing to suggest I'd be willing to do anything German, so obviously no VPN there either. If the ad would be in Chinese it'd be the same: no association of me whatsoever there.

Comment: You're registered there, but that doesn't necessarily mean that ip location services also think that your current IP comes from the netherland. But you can check there here: https://www.iplocation.net/ (it uses different location services and tells you there the IP maybe come from).

Comment: @Tom as expected: That website tells me that all services think I'm in the correct country. I don't live close to our borders (country's not that big, so relatively speaking) and we have our own ISPs, so there's no reason to think any of our ISPs would give us a German location.

Comment: *"I happen to speak German and live reasonably close to Germany"* – well, there you go. SO knows all that apparently. ;)

Comment: I'm somewhat more concerned about the cut off "Mitarbeitervergünstigungen"…

Comment: @deceze It is *"Mitarbeitervergünstigung"* and a small € sign ... so all in order :D.

Comment: Something something Dutch are half German anyway

Comment: Same problem here. Is there a reasonable way to let the system know I'm not interested in this job. Eventhough I'm not interested in jobs at all...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This can sometimes happen depending on how the company sets up their job listing and targeting for it.

The job itself might be in Germany, but the company might decide to target it to the whole of Europe, for example.

In general, there's several factors which determine what jobs get shown: location, how matched the job is to the person, etc. Sometimes the power of one factor overwhelms the others.

We're not yet at the point where folks can say things like: "I *only* want to work in country X" or "never show me jobs from country Y". So if you see a job which doesn't match your personal preferences, it's a limitation of the system as is, rather than us trying to present to you bad matches, or a bug in the system.

It's up to the company to configure the targeting for their job listings. They can determine which locations and other factors they want to show jobs ads to. While in the future I hope we'll be able to put similar controls in the hands of the people as well, for the time being, this means that sometimes companies make... interesting targeting choices. But these are almost always going to be less effective than correctly targeted listings, so we don't expect a ton of wrong-country/wrong-language spam from lots of companies (since they'll be paying for tons of useless impressions).

If we end up wrong about that and this starts to be a trend, we want to hear about it so we can revisit those assumptions and fix the issue, so please do keep us posted here on Meta.

Comment: Be that as it may, there's no point in targeting the whole of Europe with a German ad, as there aren't that many people outside the native-German speaking areas who speak German.

Comment: That's up to the company to configure though. They can determine if it's good for them or not. In the future I hope we'll be able to put similar controls in the hands of the people as well.

Comment: So if I decide to start a company and post a job offer in Sanskrit that's perfectly OK with you guys at SE?

Comment: As a curiosity: do you charge more money to have adds per country that it reaches? If that company paid more to announce in Adriaans country, your logic may make sense, but if they can just choose without any implication, this may lead to massive spamming on unwanted adds in other languages.

Comment: Interestingly, just after coming to this post [ads in German started to show in my page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BK97G.png), I'm in the UK

Comment: @Adriaan why would we have a problem with the language in which a posting is written?

Comment: Well, because unless the person receiving the ad clearly indicated somewhere that they speak the language in which it is written, you can't assume I speak *any* language but English, the language of the website. I'd be happy to list that I speak Dutch, German and Swedish as well somewhere, but without that all you can assume is that it'd be gibberish to me. Gibberish which in my opinion should not be there on an explicitly English speaking website, where any non-English content is immediately flagged as VLQ and deleted.

Comment: You're more than welcome to show me ads in any odd language, just be aware that the entire feature would become essentially noise if most of them are completely irrelevant due to location or language for me.

Comment: @AnderBiguri companies use this to find technical people to work for them. If they have a listing for Germany, but target it to Australia, they're not going to be very successful in their search I guess. A single company doing this (by mistake, most probably), won't cause massive spamming though of users.

Comment: Especially because it's going to be much less effective (and therefore more expensive) than more focused targeting. Market forces win the day in the general case with these ads; seems like one just slipped through the cracks in this case (probably human error, as @Horia noted).

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if there's a correlation between people who would be willing to relocate to Germany for a job like this, and people who can make sense of these short blurbs in German. So I wouldn't say that showing this ad in its current form to people outside Germany is pointless.

Comment: Apparently [it has not been improved](http://imgur.com/L9wZ75q.png), now I'm even getting French ads. (I'm fairly certain advertising in French in The Netherlands is even more of a waste of money than advertising in German). cc @hairboat

Comment: This needs to be fixed. I don't speak German and I keep getting German job ads. I don't mind working in Germany but seeing post after post all in German I wonder if I am even on an English website.