# Don't show the Salary popup if it's not supported in your country

Tags: discussion, salary-calculator

At the moment, SO pops up a link to the salary calculator, even if they don't currently support your country.

I suggest this annoying popup that basically contains false advertisement should be hidden for people from unsupported locations.

Comment: I would go as far as why are we putting a button that says NEW simply for a salary calculator?  I don't know - the scope of this site is changing dramatically and becoming more and more annoying.

Comment: But that can only work for the people like you who put in their location pretty accurately ... Location isn't a mandatory field and it is free format ...

Comment: @JonH I mostly agree with you. But I wonder if the `NEW` button is more general-purpose, and will be used to announce other new site-wide features. I still think there are better ways to do that, but it's slightly less obnoxious than a button just for the calculator.

Comment: *"We will be targeting our messages to the people who we need to communicate with. In some cases we will notify everyone on a site or the entire network, in some cases we will limit a notification to users of a specific product (e.g. Jobs or Channels) or a very small subset of a community with a particular problem (e.g. people who have a problem with their account)."* it's going to vary, you can't disable it, and can only make it go away by acknowledging it or blocking it.

Comment: Can this be expanded to not showing the salary popup even if it is supported in your country?

Comment: There is remote jobs so even if your country is not included the company you might be working for is, so it is a 50-50 thing, but nevertheless I'm with @Liam 's idea I think it is helpful if we have the choice to disable it.

Comment: I think it shouldn't either be shown to users who aren't interested in jobs (there is a "not interested in jobs" option in the profile settings). I just program for fun and I'm not really interested in how much money professional programmers earn.

Comment: Don't contribute with _your_ salary = not supported

Comment: Why not just put it in the menu on the right side under the button with some common "tools" icon.

Comment: Please give me the option to disable it, along with the nonsense job ads on the side bar. [I've complained about the locations before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344685/5211833) and besides, I do coding as *part* of my job, not as my full job (or study, in this case), and I'd never want to work as a "programmer", rather as a scientist who may happen to be programming most of the time. So please, stop showing me jobs about nonsense like iOS.

Comment: @Adriaan I think the primary reason SO shows ads is not because they think you are interested, but because they are paid to show them. Ad blockers are widely available. As an official reference, see [Tim Post's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/301225)