# 'Looking for a job': currency, localisation, 'more'

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

Even though I am already employed, I tend to have a daily look at what jobs are available to get an idea what's wanted on the market. I like this feature of SO! However, in my opinion the "Looking for a job" box can use a few updates.

Most importantly to me would be the streamlining of currency. Below is a screenshot of the box I saw this morning:

[image: Box diff currencies]

As you can see, some offers are in Euro and others in Pound. I don't like that. To easily compare jobs and what they offer, I'd like to see all of them in the same format. I am sure there are currency converter APIs available that can easily accomplish this task. The user's preference can be taken from the field in their profile where they say 'minimum salary ... {currency}', or even derived from their location/country. So I am *not* saying, restrict to only show jobs with said currency but change all jobs to show the preferred currency.

Secondly, but less important to me personally, is that some of these ads are not in English or a language that I am proficient in. The second offer seems to be in German: because I can understand Frontend, and because I am Belgian (Dutch speaking) I can derive that Entwickler (~ ontwikkelaar) means developer. But as you may understand, it is not ideal to see these ads because when I click to follow, [the whole ad](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/169773/frontend-entwickler-alturos-destinations-gmbh?med=clc) is in German (and I am not proficient enough to understand it).

Wouldn't it therefore be more appropriate to only show advertisements in the user's preferred language? I can imagine a field being added to 'Match preferences' on your profile (`/users/jobsearch/{id}`) that shows in which language you want to see ads. (If none are given, you can still show all of them.) In addition, there should be a field when creating the ad of course, where companies can specify in which language their ad is posted. (Possibly even with 'translations' linked to that specific ad.)

I think SO and the companies would benefit from this change because you more easily direct users to relevant ads and get a more effective and efficient system (relevant ad per click  as well as applied job per click).

Finally, when I first saw the box I was looking for a "more" button but instead you are expected to click the heading 'Looking for a job?'. I don't think this is clear or user-friendly and I would propose something like this:

[image: proposed 'more' link]

I believe that a simple 'more' link is much more straightforward and intuitive. The title 'Looking for a job' should then just be a heading, not a hyperlink.

Update 26 March:

Now that I've been paying more attention to it, I've also noticed that the color of the box is not always the same. I've seen blue, orange, and yellow. Please don't do this. As a user, you identify parts of a website by size, color, and its position. Don't change its color randomly. I liked the blue the most, personally.

Comment: I saw a post stating that the different colors (and changing designs) are part of A/B testing they're doing. I definitely agree that it seems to change far too often.

Comment: I'm not sure that sliently converting currencies is a good idea; if a job is going to be paying me in EUR rather than GBP, that's important information. If nothing else, saying that I'm being paid a certain amount in GBP today might turn out to be very misleading by next week when the exchange rate has crashed, or whatever.

Comment: @anaximander An alternative could be to show an approximation (given current exchange rate) in between brackets after the original currency. E.g. `£65k - £75k (~ €74k - €85.5k)`.

Answer (score 16):

Regarding the German ad...

[We require English on StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680/57475)...

Shouldn't this extend to Careers too?

Comment: The official answer to this specific question seems to be different, see [Why am I seeing a German job advert?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344685/469983)

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't mind seeing ads in my native tongue, though. It seems plausible that a Belgian firm puts out an ad in Dutch (Flandres), French (Wallonia), German (Easten Belgium) when advertising locally, and an English one to reach a more international audience. I guess I would appreciate a Dutch ad possibly more than an English one. So especially if you want to get locals involved, localisation would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

Also I would suggest having a feature where I can mention primary and secondary skills. Based on filter if I am looking for opportunities based on just primary skills it should display only those jobs. Suppose, in my skills I have Java, Python, HTML, SQL, CSS etc.Here, currently I am shown all the jobs irrespective of primary or secondary skills. Because of which I am shown all jobs having sql even with .NET which is undesirable for me.

Answer (score 2):

I don't actually agree with normalising the currency. Although it's tempting to believe that having *all* values in your local currency will make them easier to compare, this is not actually true. There is more than one exchange rate, and comparing currency in any meaningful way requires more than just an exchange rate anyway — you must consider cost of living factors that will vary wildly even between cities in the same country.

As such I believe it is far better to keep the values in their original currency, as advertised. Use research to determine a rough conversion factor in your head and over time you will read the values intuitively.

Comment: Even though I get the gist of what you are saying, I don't completely agree. Of course there is a difference in living cost, as you rightfully point out, but as you also said: this also differs between cities in the same country. So the point still stands that to compare, it is easier to have some sort of common ground to do the calculations and comparisons in your head. For instance, when I go abroad (e.g. Britain) I'll still 'count back' to euros when I buy a sandwich, just to get a general idea of how much I am spending. It eases the cognitive effort to have an idea of quantity.

Comment: But following yours and anaximander's reply, I propose to not remove the initial currency, but to simply provide an indication in the user's preferred currency, e.g. by providing it between brackets after the original: `£65k - £75k (~ €74k - €85.5k)`.

Comment: Even more important than different living costs might be that the term _salary_ is defined or used differently. For example, in Germany, if you talk about salary people usually think about the _employee's_ gross salary (including tax and the employee's social security contribution). But that salary number does not include the employer's contribution to the employee's social security. Therefore a €72k Germany salary actually needs to be compared to a ~€88k salary when the other country usually defines _salary_ as the total amount the employer pays to or for the employee.

Comment: Or that €72k might compare to just ~€48k (married, two kids) if you do not care about mandatory insurances and taxes and only want to compare your net salary which you would be able to spend.

Comment: @BramVanroy That seems like a fair compromise.