# Very low quality job ads from recruiters

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

I'm seeing a lot of very low quality job ads from recruiters, and I'm getting sick of reporting them. Does SO have a review process for ads? I'm not really feeling the love from SO on this TBH, feels like they're prioritising short-term recruiter $$ rather than respecting the mission and community (not saying this is true but it's what it seems like).

I understand that the SO jobs policy allows recruiters to post job ads as long as they mention the company name somewhere in the ad, however IMO this is a pretty poor UX to have to trawl through paragraphs to find the company name.

Also recruiters seem to not understand that the Industry field is for the industry of the job not the industry of the recruiter (or maybe this is a limitation of the SO CRM platform). e.g. 
https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/194023/hiring-application-developers-data-analysts-hays-plc?med=clc

Would SO consider changing the company-name line in job postings to actual companies only?

It's really upsetting for me, I'm pretty close to ad-blocking SO jobs.

Comment: It would be neat if we could actually flag a job ad with a VLQ flag.

Comment: I came in here expecting Crossover...

Comment: Not [1998](https://www.eyrie.org/~eagle/writing/rant.html) again, I hope.

Comment: Wouldn't the propper solution be to have these recruiters set a hybrid company name. I see that a lot in my network's. Something like (from your example) "Hays plc for University of Melbourne"

Comment: Anything non-English on the site is usually VLQ as well, [unless someone paid them for that content](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344685/5211833). Quality is out the window as soon as money can be earned.

Comment: In my personal experience SO jobs is more hit & miss then linkedin & co are. Better off using SO for what SO is good for and linkedin for what linkedin is good for

Comment: this post caught my attention when an ad for a job needing c# and rest skills was entitled "Java developer" ... java was only mentioned in the small mentions in the job....

Comment: linkedin is good for something?

Comment: @NickCardoso  What's wrong with having one well-arranged source of You previous experience, education etc, which can be easily found and compared by employers or future colleagues?

Comment: Let's hope VLQ job ads won't end in a review queue...

Comment: I will give props to SO Jobs for not allowing people to contact me (through SO Jobs) if I set that preference. LinkedIn lets people contact me if they know my brother's wife's second cousin's dog's sister.

Comment: @BugFinder I reported an ad just yesterday that was tagged [Unity3d] despite having *no* mention of the engine anywhere in the job description, job title, or even a vague passing reference that might be interpreted as relevant (e.g. "Game Developer role"). It's not the first, second, or even fourth such ad I've reported.