# Turn off highlighted jobs email for single company?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

I have the following alert settings for my jobs (nothing is in the "Job Alerts" section).

[image: Job Alerts]

Occasionally, I get emails highlighting special jobs. (Hooray! That's my setting). The problem is, I've now gotten this email twice and it features the company I currently work for.

Can I exclude my company from these occasional highlights without turning this feature off completely?

Comment: *I've now gotten this email twice and it features the company I currently work for* ... the matching algorithm works ...

Comment: Ha. I suppose the good news is that it isn't *my* job being featured.

Comment: [You'll probably find the answer will be no...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344686/833070): *"It's up to the company to configure the targeting for their job listings"*