# Don't show job descriptions writing in languages the user cannot read

Tags: discussion, status-deferred, languages, stack-overflow-jobs

At the moment when you live in the Netherlands, Stack Overflow Jobs will show jobs from Germany, while this is fine, this creates the problem of Stack Overflow jobs assuming that I understand the German language.

An example here:

[image]

The job description should either be translated to English, or the job should be hidden from view.

This post is not a duplicate of [Provide option to filter jobs by natural languages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321006/provide-option-to-filter-jobs-by-natural-languages) as that post talks about the mail from jobs, but my post is about the jobs recommendations you get as advertisements.

Comment: If you cannot read German, it seems unlikely that you would be a good candidate for that job. So not displaying these jobs at all would be more sensible than translating them, only to hide the surprise.

Comment: @CodyGray I have to disagree with that, inside the company where I work there are multiple people who cannot read or write Dutch, and we communicate in english with them

Comment: Surely your browser or an extension of it can help with translating from German, if you want to read an ad in German. I don't think the site should decide for a user if they want to read such an ad or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you for your feedback.  You raise an excellent point: seeing content in a language you don't read isn't useful.

We have explored some options for language-tagging job postings and using info from, say, [your browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Language) to determine which jobs to show you.  There are a number of complexities in this approach, and it's not a project that has made it to the top of the priority heap just yet.  Occasionally, employers post job listings in multiple languages, so that's another wrinkle.

We prefer to show you only relevant jobs, and we're always looking for ways to improve how we do so.  Feedback like yours helps us know what to prioritize, so thanks again.