# Prevent receiving job messages in languages you cannot understand

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs, languages, jobs-messages

I've received a job message from a company in a language I cannot understand. I live in Luxembourg, which puts me on the border of Belgium, France and Germany. I however cannot speak German (Nor do I indicate I can on my profile) but have received a jobs message in German:

[image: Image of job message]

Is there anyway to prevent this and only receive job messages in a language I can understand? I'm clearly not a good fit for the company as I can't speak the language, so it seems a bit random.

Comment: Let alone the spelling mistakes - this letter sounds poorly formulated and can be considered as spam IMO.. Additionally: If they don't even address you in the polite form it's quite unprofessional..

Comment: It's not from a company, it's from a recruiter.  "mein Kunde" == my customer.  Ought to be a [ToS violation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277369/a-terms-of-service-update-restricting-companies-that-scrape-your-profile-informa), send his name and details to team@stackoverflow.com

Comment: @HansPassant This wasn't done via email, I received this via the internal [Stack Overflow jobs messaging system](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/messages). I'm assuming they are paying a monetary amount to SO to be able to contact potential employees.

Comment: Sure, that makes it easier for them to stop him.

Comment: @HansPassant But they haven't scraped my info, they used the tools SO have provided to them via the Stack Overflow jobs page. AFAIK, they don't have access to my email nor any real details apart from knowing that I'm an SO user

Comment: [You could reply with: *I ... think .. I just need to be held right now. I've got Mookey the stuffed bear, but I'm not in a very good place.*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/318622/5515060)

Comment: My first thought when I saw this topic was "You mean like Perl?"

Comment: @IanKemp This wasn't an email about possible job listings, but a direct communication from a recruiter, so it's not SO jobs sending me the message but SO allowing a recruiter to send a message to me in a foreign language

Comment: VTC as a dupe of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321006/provide-option-to-filter-jobs-by-natural-languages - the tl;dr is SO doesn't care and isn't going to fix this, because they get paid per impression, regardless of how useful that impression is. See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344686/70345